# XSLT date formatting template and Attribute Value Templates

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT transformation and have encountered a problem, I have created a date format template.

This is working fine when using standard tagging e.g.  (formatting a date from 2012-06-08T00:00:00 to 2012-06-08).  However I need to apply this tempalte to an XSLT using Attribute Value Templates and cannot find the proper way to do this e.g. as the below:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xsi"
        xmlns:ted="Report1"
        >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />


        <xsl:template match="/ted:Report">

            <Root XSDVersion="{$XSDVersion}">

                    <Person>

                    <xsl:for-each select="ted:table1/ted:Detail_Collection/ted:Detail">

                            <Record>

                            <xsl:variable name="DOB">
                              <xsl:call-template name="formatDateYYYY-MM-DD">
                                <xsl:with-param name="DTM" select="ted:TUserInput/ted:Details_Collection/ted:Details/@DOB" />
                            </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:variable>                                                     
                                <Details    ID="{normalize-space(@ID)}"
                                            Surname="{@Surname}"
                                            Title="{normalize-space(@Title)}"
                                            DOB="{$DOB}"/>
                            </Record>
                    </Person>
            </Root>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: In an attribute value template you can use that variable that you created e.g. `<Details DOB="{$DOB}" .../>`.

Comment: I am using the <Details DOB="{$DOB}"  as you suggested but I still have no  values in the DOB elements.  If I revert to <Details DOB="{@DOB}"  I'll get all values without formatting.

Comment: Consider to edit your question and provide minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT code and current and wanted output to allow us to reproduce the problem. Currently, with only some XSLT lines, it is not clear whether you do not select the right input nodes or whether there is a different problem.